# Resize Layout according to banner view's appearance

Tags: ios, swift, admob, iad

I have an app that is currently published on AppStore. Now I am trying to change my advertisement strategy. I am trying to implement an algorithm like " show iAd, if it fails show admob"
I followed the code [iAd Admob mediation with singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31210886/iad-admob-mediation-with-singleton/31755359#31755359)
I have a problem with implementation below. Everything seems fine except banner view is overlaying my main view. As I said before this app was distributed so far, so I am trying to do it without changing my previous layout and auto layout constraints. I want my previous view will auto resize according to appearance of banner view. When banner will appear, main view should shrink then will enlarge if banner cannot get any ad.

**It overlays my main view elements.**
[image: It overlays my main view elements]

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
var iAdBanner = ADBannerView()
var adMobBanner = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeBanner)

//Banner View Code

func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {

    UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
    iAdBanner.alpha = 1.0
    adMobBanner.alpha = 0.0
    UIView.commitAnimations()
    NSLog("iAd loaded ad")
}

func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {


    UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
    iAdBanner.alpha = 0.0
    adMobBanner.alpha = 1.0
    UIView.commitAnimations()
    NSLog("iAd failed to load ad")

}

func adView(view: GADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: GADRequestError!) {

    println("We dont have admob hide it!")

    adMobBanner.alpha = 0
}

func adViewDidReceiveAd(view: GADBannerView!) {

    if iAdBanner.alpha == 0.0 {
        println("No IAD show admob")
        adMobBanner.alpha = 1.0

    }
}
```

**Registration.swift**

```
class Registration: NSObject {

var appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate //non-optional variable
static var sharedInstance = Registration()

func showAds(viewController:UIViewController, view:UIView?) {
    var bannerView:UIView = view ?? viewController.view

    //Admob
    appDelegate.adMobBanner.rootViewController = viewController
    appDelegate.adMobBanner.delegate = appDelegate
    var request = GADRequest()
    appDelegate.adMobBanner.adUnitID = "ca-app"
    appDelegate.adMobBanner.loadRequest(request)
    appDelegate.adMobBanner.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    bannerView.addSubview(appDelegate.adMobBanner)
    var myConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: appDelegate.adMobBanner, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: bannerView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    bannerView.addConstraint(myConstraint)
    myConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: appDelegate.adMobBanner, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: bannerView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    bannerView.addConstraint(myConstraint)
    myConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: appDelegate.adMobBanner, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: bannerView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    bannerView.addConstraint(myConstraint)

    // iAd
    appDelegate.iAdBanner.delegate = appDelegate;
    appDelegate.iAdBanner.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    bannerView.addSubview(appDelegate.iAdBanner)
    myConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: appDelegate.iAdBanner, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: bannerView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    bannerView.addConstraint(myConstraint)

    myConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: appDelegate.iAdBanner, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: bannerView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    bannerView.addConstraint(myConstraint)

    myConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: appDelegate.iAdBanner, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: bannerView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    bannerView.addConstraint(myConstraint)

}
```

**I showed my ad in my main view controller like:**

```
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    Registration.sharedInstance.showAds(self,view:nil)
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little. You want to change size of iAd?

Comment: I think I explained well but seems not. Currently i have an app on store and want to add ad without changing my autolayout. I added ads with code above but it overlays my current view. I want it to fit to screen with my ad and resize to full screen if there is no ad. I saw some examples but could not achieve

Comment: Alright, and you want this for banner ad or full screen ad?

Comment: As its seen from both code and screenshot, its banner.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a single `UIView`, say you name it `bannerAdView` set its size whatever way you want, and show your iAd or Admob inside that view. Give frame size to iAdBanner and adMobBanner same as the `bannerAdView's bounds`

Comment: Alright, I will delete the answer then.. But then what do you want? Don't you want Banner not to overlay your main view?

Comment: Yes sure but this will not solve my problem. I think you can understand better if you can look code or maybe replicate at your end. It will work with c/p

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to your problem would be using `self.canDisplayBannerAds = true`. Simply add it to your `viewDidLoad`. Implementing your iAd banner in this way will resize your `UIView` when an ad is available and move itself off screen when an iAd banner is not available. Remove your current implementation of your `ADBannerView` and give it a try. There are downsides to using `self.canDisplayBannerAds = true` though, like not being able to use the `ADBannerView`'s delegate methods. I'd assume you could check your `UIView` to see if it contains an `ADBannerView` or not and act upon it accordingly if you'd like.

Comment: I knew that implementation and my current app on store has ads like that. Main purpose of those codes above is combining admob and iAd. So this will not be an answer for my question

Comment: Actually this implementation is Swift version of exact your code at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29917987/rotate-ipad-and-admob-to-not-load-again-like-iads/ Problem in that implementation is that overlaying issue. You may help better since its your code's variation

Comment: @batgun I'm glad my code was able to help you implement your banner ads. That code was never intended to behave in the manner you are trying to achieve. To accomplish what you are looking for, I'd suggest pinning the bottom of your `view` to the top of your `GADBannerView` and `ADBannerView`. Then, when you don't have an ad move the banner/banners just off the bottom of the screen. The thing is AdMob has a near 100% fill rate so the chance of your app not receiving any ads is slim. Do you have an in app purchase to remove the ads also?

Comment: Thanks for reply. When I pin those views, banner disappears completely.Probably I am missing something there. As you can see I change the alphas for removing banner. I will implement in app purchase to remove ads too after resolving that frustrating problem